# Which one is better among <c:import> and <jsp:include> in terms of performance?

Tags: jsp, jstl

i am using import jstl tag, is it better to use jsp:include instead of import?

```
<c:choose>      
    <c:when test="${item.id=='masters'}">    
        <c:import url="/newclickmenu/mastermenuitems.jsp"></c:import>    
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${item.id=='sales'}">   
        <c:import url="/newclickmenu/salesmenuitems.jsp"></c:import>   
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`<c:import>` will offer a flexibility, and functionality improvement in addition to `<jsp:include>`.

- `<c:import>` will allow you to specify content from other web applications, and contexts, as well as web servers; this gives you more flexibility.
- Keep in mind though, that a static include, is always faster than a dynamic one; meaning
  that`<%@ include file="" %>` is faster than both `<jsp:include>` and `<c:import>`.
- Technically, `<c:import>` should only be used if you require its functionality, or flexibility, the improvement in performance is minimal.
- Some might state that implementing `<c:import>` is bad practice if you do not need it due to it being more heavy weight than `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: can <c;import> access pages with in the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: yes, as my above code, i am importing them from my war folder.

Comment: @M.S.Naidu Sorry, for the editing; I figured it was too much to put in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

One important advantage of c:import is that it can include the external resources like other web application from the current context.